# How to merge all tables data between 2 identical databases

Tags: sql-server, join, merge

I have a database that stores data every 10 minutes. I have 2 backups of this database and i want to join data of all tables. That is, ignore repeated values and insert differents values.

I read about merge command:

```
MERGE DESTINO AS DESTINO
USING FONTE AS FONTE
ON DESTINO.INDICE = FONTE.DESTINO

WHEN MATCHED 
--IGNORE

WHEN NOT MATCHED
--INSERT ROW ...
```

But is valid for one table.
Is there a command to do this for all tables between two databases?

Comment: *"Is there a command to do this for all tables between two databases"* Nope; you need to run a `MERGE`/UPSERT against each table. There is no "magic" fix my design button/feature.

Comment: No there isn't. You will need to do this one table at a time. Stop looking for shortcuts. You WILL need to allow for foreign keys and primary keys - I suspect this process will be more difficult than you imagine.

Comment: What is your target solution? A primary database (updated every 10 minutes) with 2 up-to-date secondary backup databases? Sounds like you want some form of [database replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication) or [database mirroring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server).